# How to create NWConnection

Tags: ios, swift

**Premise**

I'm using Apple's Network framework to create a peer-to-peer app. What I'm currently trying to do is:

1. Device A establishes a connection with Device B and sends data.
2. Device B *saves* the `NWConnection` information of Device A.
3. Device B establishes a connection with Device A again using the saved [MWConnection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwconnection) information and sends data.

I modelled off Apple's [demo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/building_a_custom_peer-to-peer_protocol), which is essentially this [source code](https://github.com/cntrump/Tic-Tac-Toe/tree/master/TicTacToe) here.  Unlike Apple's demo, which establishes a single two-way connection and maintains that connection at all times, my app connects to multiple devices that can drop in and out of the connections at any time.  This is why I want to be able to a) distinguish a specific device and b) initiate a new connection.

**Problem**

The problem I'm having is being able to reconstruct the `NWConnection` object using the information provided when a connection has been established. There are two ways of instantiating this object.

1. `init(host: NWEndpoint.Host, port: NWEndpoint.Port, using: NWParameters)`
2. `init(to: NWEndpoint, using: NWParameters)`

My attempts have been trying to gather the endpoint information like the host and the port while the connection with the desired device has been established and instantiate `NWEndpoint` to be used in `NWConnection`.  But, I haven't been able to re-establish the connection thus far.

Following is the portion of the object that is used to initiate a connection. My full code is modified, but Apple's counterpart can be seen [here](https://github.com/cntrump/Tic-Tac-Toe/blob/master/TicTacToe/TicTacToe/Networking/PeerConnection.swift).

```swift
class PeerConnection {
    
    weak var delegate: PeerConnectionDelegate?
    weak var statusDelegate: StatusDelegate?
    var connection: NWConnection?
    let initiatedConnection: Bool
    
    init(endpoint: NWEndpoint, interface: NWInterface?, passcode: String, delegate: PeerConnectionDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.initiatedConnection = true
        
        let connection = NWConnection(to: endpoint, using: NWParameters(passcode: passcode))
        self.connection = connection
        
        startConnection()
    }
    
    init(connection: NWConnection, delegate: PeerConnectionDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.connection = connection
        self.initiatedConnection = false
        
        startConnection()
    }

    // Handle starting the peer-to-peer connection for both inbound and outbound connections.
    func startConnection() {
        guard let connection = connection else {
            return
        }
        
        connection.stateUpdateHandler = { newState in
            switch newState {
                case .ready:
                    print("\(connection) established")
                    
                    // When the connection is ready, start receiving messages.
                    self.receiveNextMessage()
                    
                    // Notify your delegate that the connection is ready.
                    if let delegate = self.statusDelegate {
                        delegate.showConnectionStatus(.connectionSuccess("Connection Success"))
                    }
                case .failed(let error):
                    print("\(connection) failed with \(error)")
                    
                    // Cancel the connection upon a failure.
                    connection.cancel()
                    
                    // Notify your delegate that the connection failed.
                    if let delegate = self.statusDelegate {
                        delegate.showConnectionStatus(.connectionFail("Connection Fail"))
                    }
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
        
        // Start the connection establishment.
        connection.start(queue: .main)
    }
}
```

This is how I receive data when another device sends it.

```swift
func receiveNextMessage() {
    guard let connection = connection else {
        return
    }
    
    /// Has to call itself again within the closure because the maximum message is once.
    connection.receiveMessage { (content, context, isComplete, error) in
        // Extract your message type from the received context.
        if let message = context?.protocolMetadata(definition: GameProtocol.definition) as? NWProtocolFramer.Message {
            self.delegate?.receivedMessage(content: content, message: message, connection: connection)
        }
        if error == nil {
            // Continue to receive more messages until you receive and error.
            self.receiveNextMessage()
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, following is how I attempt to reconstruct `MWConnection`:

```swift
func receivedMessage(content: Data?, message: NWProtocolFramer.Message, connection: NWConnection) {
    switch(connection.endpoint) {
        case .hostPort(let host, let port):
            

            /// first attempt
            let endpoint = NWEndpoint.hostPort(host: host, port: port)
            let newConnection = PeerConnection(endpoint: endpoint, interface: nil, passcode: passcode, delegate: self)
            
            /// second attempt
            let connection = NWConnection(host: host, port: port, using: NWParameters(passcode: passcode))
            let newConnection = PeerConnection(connection: connection, delegate: self)

            
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

`NWConnection` is instantiated inside initializer of `PeerConnection`.

Comment: The `port` you will have from an incoming packet isn't the port you want to connect to.  The port you receive will be a random high port associated with that specific connection.  You can grab the `host`, but the port you will want to connect back to is the port you set up to `listen` on when you set everything up; the same port that device A used to connect to device B.  Is there a reason that you don't want to maintain a connection?  Continually setting up and tearing down TCP connections is relatively expensive and slow. It costs almost nothing to keep a connection alive

Comment: If you don't want a long lived connection you may be better off using UDP rather than TCP.  You could also look at the Multipeer Connectivity Framework which abstracts all of the network code away.

Comment: @Paulw11 when you say `listen`, are you referring to `NWListener`? I've set up `listener.newConnectionHandler` as well, but it seems to produce the exact same objects with the same ports and hosts as `NWConnection`.  `NWBrowser.Result` however seems to produce objects that are a bit different. But, this is from browsing, and not when a device sends data. Could you explain how I would be able to get the port you mentioned?

Comment: There are two ports involved. There is the port you are connecting *to* - This is a fixed port number that you nominate and that your server is *listening on*.  Your client makes a connection to that port.  The client will send its data from some random port; When the server replies to the client, that is the port where the reply is sent. What you are then trying to do is reverse the client and server roles; So you need device "A" to make a connection to device "B".  It will do so on the same fixed port number that you nominated (And device B needs to be *listening* on that port).

Comment: In summary, you need device A to record the *host* part of the incoming connection from device B but the port isn't needed; Device A needs to know the fixed port number you have decided to use and that device B will be listening on.  If you are using connection-oriented TCP it is much better to just leave the connection in place rather than keep tearing them down and reconnecting.

Comment: I've explored UDP as well, but the actual frequency of the tear down & reconnect is not gonna be a lot so I think TCP makes sense for me. So I understood what you said about "reversing the client and server roles".  I had the client notify the server "hey this is the port I'm listening on" then had the server send a message to that listener as if it was the client. I did this by combining the host grabbed like I did in my code above, but instead of using the randomized port, I used the listener port sent by the client to create `NWConnection`.  Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I'm curious tho.  Instead of reversing the roles, how does a server send a message to a specific client when there are multiple clients connected to the server? I mean even if a server is not initiating connections and the connections have already been established by the clients, the server would have to pick from one of the already existing connections to send a message to a particular client, right? I'm not quite sure how to find out the existing connections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242090/discussion-between-paulw11-and-kevvv).

Comment: Looks like Multipeer connectivity is [broken](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663772). Apple acknowledges it and recommends using Network instead.